# Is there any advantage in using Google Hosted Libraries instead of local versions?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to developing web sites, and I've seen a lot of sites that use Google hosted libraries... Is there any advantage in using Google Hosted Libraries instead of local versions?

Comment: True. Not the most exact duplicate example, but there sure are alot of them.

Comment: Thanks, just for the record... I wasn't thinking specifically of jQuery, maybe that's why my search didn't show any results...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are a few advantages you have with Google hosted libraries.

1) It is delivered through CDN's (Content Delivery Network)
2) Better caching because of CDN
3) Low Latency - CDN distributes your content across various locations; hence reducing the latency.

Also be careful when you are using a Google hosted library. You will have to make sure you have a fallback mechanism incase the connection to Google library fails. Like downloading the file from your own server, if the earlier download failed.